# Count number of occurrence of each word in python is a set of string?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have the following 3 sentences that I searched for in a text and appended them to the list `sentence` using `sentence.append()`

For example

```
sentence[0]=" hello my name is John"
sentence[1]="good morning I am John"
sentence[2]= "hello I am Smith"
```

I want to assign a score for each sentence and each word based on the number of occurrences of each word in all the 3 sentences.

for example:

```
Hello score= 2 since it appeared twice **SOLVED**
sentence[0] score= hello score( which is 2) + my (1) + name (1) + is (1) + John(2) = 6
```

So I used that to count the occurrence (score) of each word in the sentence, **my question is how can I use it to calculate the score of the sentence ?**

```
dict = {}
for sentenceC in sentence:
    for word in re.split('\s', sentenceC): # split with whitespace
        try:
            dict[word] += 1
        except KeyError:
            dict[word] = 1
print (dict)
```

Comment: So... what's the question?

Comment: Sorry it was incomplete, but I completed it, I want to know how can I make use of the word count to calculate the sentence score

Comment: I understand that the score of "hello" is 2, but I don't understand what you want for "`sentence[0] score`"

Comment: Its like I want to calculate how strong is the sentence based on the frequency of its words in all the other sentences, so Sentence0 score should be=6 (why? because "hello" score is 2 & "my" score is 1 and so on) . Its a small preprocessing step for my NLP project.

Answer (score 0):

Break the problem up into subtasks

```
def getWordScores(sentences):
   scores = {}
   for sentence in sentences:
      for word in sentence.strip().split():
          word = word.lower()
          scores[word] = scores.get(word,0) + 1
   return scores

def getSentenceScore(sentence, word_scores):
   return sum(word_scores.get(w.lower(), 0) for w in sentence.strip().split())
```

Then compose the tasks to get the solution

```
word_scores = getWordScores(sentence)
print word_scores['hello']
print getSentenceScore(sentence[0], word_scores)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your score like this:

```
import re

sentence = list()

sentence.append(" hello my name is John")
sentence.append("good morning I am John")
sentence.append("hello I am Smith")

value = dict()
for sentenceC in sentence:
    for word in sentenceC.strip().split(" "): # split with whitespace
        try:
            value[word.lower()] += 1
        except KeyError:
            value[word.lower()] = 1
print (value)

score = dict()
number = 1
for sentenceC in sentence:
    for word in sentenceC.strip().split(" "): # split with whitespace
        try:
            score[number] += value[word.lower()]
        except KeyError:
            score[number] = value[word.lower()]
    number += 1

print score

#output: {1: 7, 2: 8, 3: 7}
```